# Is Ars Boni Cantus a good construction?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'm trying to create a tag line for a product in Latin and want it to be correct.
Goals:

1. should form the acronym ABC. Bonus points for suggestions that create ABCD.
2. I'm going for something along the lines of 'the art of good singing' but variations on that that still make sense in both languages would be fine.

As best as I can tell Ars Boni Cantus might be correct but would some variation of Artis Bonae Cantum be better?

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 11):

*Ars Bene Canendi* would be the actual translation for "the art of singing well." What you have now is "the art of a good song."

If you would like a D, a simple suggestion would be to add *digna* "worthy" to the end: the worthy art of singing well.